# creating a workflow to automatically move an item from a list on one page that is a certain age to another page's list

Tags: list, designer-workflow

I am having trouble getting a workflow to work with sharepoint and the 2 lists/pages I have created.

I have 2 webpages (on the same site both under ths same list directory), each with a list (same columns), and one of the pages will be my "archived" version of the other. There is 2 problems I have currently with it.

1) the workflow created is a simple one done in designer that literally states:
   if current item:Date is greater than 1/1/2017 8:00:00 AM
       copy item in current item to other list name
       then email admin about the copy/delete

I made the flow like this to test whether it works, but for some reason when I click on a list item in the web browser, and then click on the workflow and run it, all it does is add a column to the list and put a checkmark, without copying to the other page/list.

I would like to get it to copy to that other list, and then i'll add a line to delete from the current list/current item. Am I missing steps here?

2) After getting this workflow setup and working, is there a way to make the workflow automatic so that it works for all items in the list? Also, is there an option I can put in instead of a set date (like if the item is over so many months old rather than a specific date)?

The main reason I would like to do this is because the main list is currently at 5002 items, and since my company has the 5000 limit, we can't view the whole list. And since we have to keep backups to have records of interations with customers, we can't just delete the items out of the list, hence the 2nd page with the "archived" list.

EDIT: Is there a way to see what all is the same and different between the lists? I have checked on the site (via browser) that both have the same columns, but when I do a site workflow, it keeps saying to make sure the source/destination lists have the same columns/column settings. The only thing different between them that I can see is that used in is different between them (the original has some that say sharepoint server workflow task, but i can't find that option to put into the new list columns under the content type). Other than some of the used in being different, I can't figure out what to check for.

Comment: Which version of Sharepoint?

Comment: Either 2010 or 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the Cloud Flow / Logic Apps can handle that out of the box using timer based runs

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/88569)

Comment: True, but suggesting a different approach can be even better then a correct answer 

Comment: What is the Cloud Flow/Logic Apps?